# How to store value generated from nested for loop in an array, in Matlab?

Tags: arrays, matlab, for-loop, store

```
y = find(sA);
l = y + sA;

for i=1:10
  for j=1
      l = l + sA;
  end
  y = y + length(y);
end
```

I would like to know how to store the value that is generated for `l`, for each iteration, in an array.

When I try do something like l(l) = l + sA; I obtain 'weird' results.

NOTE: PLEASE READ MY COMMENTS POSTED BELOW. THANKS!

Comment: NOTE: if you have material additional to your original question, edit your question rather than direct people to read your comments.

Answer (score 0):

For a complex loop, usually I do something like this:

```
results = zeros(expectedLength,1);
ixNextResult = 1;

for ixForLoop1 = 1:10
    for ixForLoop2 = 20:30
        ..
        results(ixNextResult) = calculationResult;
        ixnextResult = ixNextResult + 1;
    end
end
```

I'm having a hard time understanding what your code is trying to accomplish, so I'm not sure what to change.  For example the snippet `l(l) = l+sA` does not make a lot of sens to me.

Comment: The l(l) = l+sA was my horrible attempt at taking this advice into account: http://blogs.mathworks.com/pick/2007/08/20/matlab-basics-video/

Comment: What I want to achieve with this code: I have an array of digits. e.g. x = [4,9,8]. I use find(x) to obtain [1,2,3], then find(x)+length(x) to obtain [4,5,6]. I want this(in this case, adding 3 to the array) to go on n number of times, so I require a loop. Now with the array x, I want to add [4,9,8] to [1,2,3] , which

Comment: Gives [5,11,11]. I have [1,2,3]...[10,11,12]...[n,n+1,n+2] from find(x)+length(x) looped, I want to add elements in x to the elements in corresponding positions in the array that is going up in three. So, for example, [4,5,6] 5 is in position 2. x=[4,9,8]. 9 is in position 2 within x. Therefore, I want to add 9 to 5. I want to do this for each element (in this case, each of the three elements).

Comment: Hope that helps clarify my aim - I have tried a few methods, but failed only slightly each time, and as a result, am frustrated!

Comment: Just to continue my example, I would add 9 to 11, and 9 to 11 as both numbers are in position '2' in their respective arrays. Thanks

Comment: It's still not clear.  Let's step back to inputs and outputs.  For an input of `x=[4 9 8]` what output do you want?  Then, what output do you want for the case where (for example) `x=[7 3 1 4]`?  I suspect that whatever you are trying to accomplish is actually pretty easy.

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

```
y = find(sA); %This is incredibly strange! What exactly are you trying to achieve with this line?
l = y + sA;

for i=1:10
  l = l + sA;
  StoredL(i, :) = l;
  y = y + length(y); %This line does nothing??? Why is it here?
end
```

I removed your inner loop as it was doing nothing, for j = 1 will only ever run once so what's the point?