# How would I go about this task- Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, for-loop, nested, element

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to store value generated from nested for loop in an array, in Matlab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12272559/how-to-store-value-generated-from-nested-for-loop-in-an-array-in-matlab)

I have an array of digits. e.g. x = [4,9,8]. I use find(x) to obtain [1,2,3], then find(x)+length(x) to obtain [4,5,6].

I want this(in this case, adding 3 to the array, to make a sequence of 1,2,3 4,5,6 7,8,9...) to go on n number of times, so I require a loop.

Now with the array x, I want to add [4,9,8] to [1,2,3] , which gives [5,11,11].

I have [1,2,3]...[10,11,12]...[n,n+1,n+2] from find(x)+length(x) looped, I want to add elements in x to the elements in corresponding positions, in the array that is going up in three.

So, for example, [4,5,6] 5 is in position 2. x=[4,9,8]. 9 is in position 2 within x. Therefore, I want to add 9 to 5. I want to do this for each element (in this case, each of the three elements). I would add 9 to 11, and 9 to 11 as both numbers are in position '2' in their respective arrays.

I was thinking of using a nested for loop, to take care of the find(x)+length(x). I am just unsure of how to make the 'location additions' happen.

I would then like to store the results of the additions in a separate array.

Thanks in advance for your time and help!

Comment: I have tried using a nested for loop, I can get the sequences fine, just not the right additions - i.e. those based on location. So far, I can only get e.g. [4,9,8] adding to [1,2,3] to make [5,11,11] then [4,9,8] adding to [4,5,6] to make [8,14,14]. Which is not really what I'm after.

Comment: The input you start with is `x = [4, 9, 8]`.  I am having trouble seeing what output you are after though... For instance, why don't you want [4,9,8] + [4,5,6] = [8,14,14]?  That seems perfectly reasonable to me.

Comment: my desired output would be, for that step, [14,20,20]. This would be obtained by adding 9 to the array [5,11,11].  9 corresponds to the 2nd position in x. In my series arrays (those which are [1,2,3] [4,5,6] [7,8,9] [10,11,12] ....) I want to add the elements from x to the elements in the series arrays based on their positions. So, since 5 and 11 are in the 2nd positions of their arrays, I want to add 9 to them, as 9 is in the 2nd position within x.

Comment: You already posted a [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12272559/).

Answer (score 1):

So, we start with

```
x = [4,9,8]
```

Let's add `[1, 2, 3]`

```
x + [1, 2, 3]
ans =
     5    11    11
```

A more flexible way

```
x + (1 : length(x))
ans =
     5    11    11
```

If you do not want to start at 1 but at `b` (say, we add `[5, 6, 7]` to `x`):

```
b = 5;
x + b + (0 : length(x) - 1)
ans =
     9    15    15
```

I think this should get you going and you can add your loop now.

**Warning:** You have a very strange way of using `find()`. Just to make sure: `find(x)` returns the indices of the non-zero entries in `x`. If all elements of the vector `x` are non-zero, you have the equality

```
find(x) == 1 : length(x)
```

If any element in `x` is zero, you run into problems, when adding it to `find(x)`:

```
x = [4, 9, 0, 8];
find(x)
ans =
     1     2     4

x + find(x)
Error using  + 
Matrix dimensions must agree.
```